# iOS simulator in windows

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have developed a responsive site. Now I want to check it for iPhone. I don't have iPhone. I came to know about iOS simulator. I am a windows user. Is it possible to use iOS simulator for testing in windows? If yes then which one and will it output as if real iPhone? I mean output will be 90% / 100% etc similar to real iPhone?

Comment: The Apple iOS simulator only works on OS X.  Do you not have a friend or colleague who has an iPad or an iPhone?

Comment: :( Sorry I have no friend with iPad or iPhone. So why I wanted a simulator working in windows.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, Safari has a way to send the User-Agent string as an iOS device, and it may do a bit more fancy rendering emulations behind the scenes. I would try looking at Safari for Windows for similar features.